# Storing multiple contracts under one clients name SQL

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm working on a school project, very simple database so my knowledge is very limited.[image]

Klient = Client
Smlouva = Contract

The database basically just keeps track of approx. 50 contracts, 35 clients and 6 insurance companies with different types of contracts.
I'm trying to assign multiple contracts to one client. ID_smlouva acts as a FK to the Client table.

insert into Klient
VALUES (1, 989, 'John', 'McDavid', 23, 1)
(1, 989, 'John', 'McDavid', 23, 2)
doesn't work because I'm simply duplicating PK.

Any other simple way to do this as I haven't been able to understand any other tips about this topic out there? :D
THX a lot!

Comment: Think about the relationship a bit more & which direction that relationship goes. Which is the "parent" and which is the "child"? Can clients have multiple contracts? Can contracts have multiple clients?

Comment: Well, Clients can have multiple contracts. Contracts cannot have multiple clients, I started with filling out the contracts table first and now I'm having trouble with filling the Client table. I can't see how that helps I am sorry, as I said my knowledge - limited ..

Comment: You have given the answer yourself: a client can have many contracts (or also no contract) and a contract can only exist for one customer. 

This means a 0-to-many relationship between clients and contracts. Think about the orientation of the foreign key constraint in cases like that. Surely you must have been told about that in class otherwise you would not be asked to develop an example to illustrate the concept

Comment: Oh okay.. I'm currently working with 1-to-many so I suppose that's where the issue comes from. I thought that it depends on the certain database as I will not store any clients without contracts I thought the relationship should be 1:M.
I surely was told that in class but I'm working in a different field and I've started studying software as a complete beginner a couple months ago so it gets overwhelming at times O:) thank you for your help

Comment: No, the issue is that you are using foreign keys the wrong way. To express a 1-to-many relationship from a "parent" entity (here your clients) to a "child" entity (here your contracts) means the foreign key goes from the "child" to the "parent". I.e. your contracts table (the "child") needs a column that contains the id of the client that contract belongs to: the foreign key is on the "child" table and points to the "parent" table.

Comment: Let me write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's summarize the issue in your own words: *"Clients can have multiple contracts. Contracts cannot have multiple clients"*

This means a **1-to-many** relationship between **clients** and **contracts**. Expressing a 1-to-many relationship from a "*parent*" entity (here your clients) to a "*child*" entity (here your contracts) in a relational database is done via *referential integrity*, i.e by using *primary* and *foreign* keys.

It means that the foreign key goes **from** the "*child*" to the "*parent*". I.e. your **contracts** table (the "child") needs a column that contains the id of the client that contract belongs to: the **foreign key** is on the **contracts** table and points to the **clients** table.

As for the distinction between **0-to-many** (like above) vs **1-to-many**, it is rather important. In real life the parent/child relationships are pretty much always **0-to-many**: meaning that a parent can exist without any children. This is the case for your example when using a plain foreign key: a **client** can exist without any **contract**. It will be the case at least for a short period when the customer first registers, then later on starts opening contracts. During that period, the *parent* (**client**) exists without any *child* (**contract**). That is pretty much always the case in real world applications.

Enforcing a **strict 1-to-many** is difficult. It will require additional logic to make sure that no ever client exists without any contract. That can be done via triggers but raises all sorts of questions:

- How can I **register a new client** (= insert a row in the client table) since at that time, no contract exists yet. And vice versa, how can I insert a contract if the client does not yet exist ? Most databases solve this by **deferring** the verification of constraints until the end of the transaction: you can then insert the client and a contract, then commit and integrity will be checked at that point.
- What happens when **I delete the last contract** for a client ? Should that imply the **automatic deletion** of the client ? Or should it be **prevented** since a client must have at least one contract ? Both have painful consequences and are not trivial to implement.

Then you have **insurance companies**. This presents an additional challenge. You have essentially two options depending on whether a client is allowed to own contracts with multiple companies, or whether a client is with one insurance company only.

- **In case #1** (a client is allowed to own contracts with multiple companies), then there is a 1-to-many relationship (actually again 0-to-many for ease of use) between **insurance companies** and **contracts**. Which means a foreign key from **contracts** to **companies**
- **In case #2** (a client is with one insurance company only), then that means that **all** contracts for that client belong to the same insurance company. That is then better represented by a 1-to-many between **companies** and **clients**. Which therefore means a foreign key from **clients** to **companies** this time.

At this point, it is a good idea for you to re-read the specification you have been given, especially to understand the relationship between companies and contract / customers. Misunderstanding those things is a common cause for implementing wrong designs that do not meed the application requirements. Any ambiguity must be lifted at the very beginning.

Comment: thank you very much